# Can my child enter the US on a foreign passport?

Tags: usa, uk, customs-and-immigration, passports

My child is entitled to US citizenship but we have been unable to register her birth abroad as due to covid we cannot get an embassy appointment. She has a valid UK passport. We need to travel to the US, will she be able to enter the US on her UK passport? She would be travelling with me (UK passport holder), my husband (US passport holder) and our other child (US passport holder).

Comment: In theory, no.  In practice, maybe, but do you want the stress?  There are already so,e similar questions here, but I couldn't find one that was so close I'd call it a duplicate.

Comment: The main issue is that to even be allowed to board, she will need an ESTA, and the ESTA form asks for other nationalities, where you should state she is also a US citizen. This *should* prevent the ESTA from being authorised, but there have been reports that people have successfully been granted an ESTA in this situation. The jury is still out on this one. The other (minor) issue is that most non-US citizens are not allowed to travel to the US from the UK at this time due to COVID. You will need to prove that she is the child of a US citizen (like you need to prove you are the spouse of one).

Comment: @jcaron both issues can be bypassed by flying via Mexico and crossing the border overland. Luckily the Mexican air border is wide open.

Comment: 'My child is entitled to US citizenship' : is your child only "entitled" or does it actually HAS US citizenship ?

Comment: @JonathanReez Unfortunately the US Southern border is NOT wide open, and the UK passport holders might not _automatically_ be exempt, so there would at least still be probability of stress while trying to cross the land border.

Comment: @JonathanReez That may be the case officially, but I know people who have had a very stressful time crossing, as although they were family they didn't have anything other than tourist visas or ESTA (ie no right to reside) so it was still difficult for them to enter.

Comment: @Midavalo but this child ought to be admitted as a US citizen by presenting the same evidence of citizenship that would be presented in connection with a passport application.

Comment: @phoog Indeed, however I would be surprised if it was an easy, stress-free crossing of the border (see my comments on the answer below).  Not to forget there's also the UK passport-holder parent.

Comment: @Hilmar we have not been able to do her consular report of a birth abroad so she doesn’t have her citizenship certificate yet or US passport. I say “entitled” because the language on the embassy website refers to children in her situation having an “entitlement” to US citizenship but despite that wording my understanding is that she is automatically a US citizen from birth by virtue of her Dad (who is a US citizen who satisfies the residency requirements to pass on citizenship)

Comment: @jcaron thank you. I hadn’t considered the ESTA questions which further complicates things. We would be able to provide proof that she is the child of a US citizen and also that I am the spouse of a US citizen. My understanding is that the two of us would be able to enter as an exception to the presidential travel ban proclamation provided we could show this proof.

Comment: thank you all for the helpful commentary on the land border options. I’m not sure that realistically will be a practical option for us travelling with small kids to our final destination but it gives me something to consider further.

Comment: @Needtottravel. can you let us know if you had any problems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best shot is to try for an ESTA.

The ESTA application will ask you specifically if you have other citizenships and  you need to answer truthfully. The rules about ESTA for US citizens are unclear and there have been cases where an ESTA was issued without problems. As with many things CBP,  the rules are vague and there is an unfortunate amount of "officer discretion".

If there is a field for comments in the application, add that you couldn't get a passport due to Covid. There are currently Covid exceptions for expired passports so maybe their is one for non-issued passports as well.

If that gets denied, you can consider a land border through Mexico or Canada. These are currently restricted due to Covid, so you need to read up on the exact details of the current conditions. The current restrictions are in place until June 21, but what happens after this is anyone's guess. See [https://www.reuters.com/world/us/us-land-border-restrictions-extended-with-canada-mexico-2021-05-20/#:~:text=United%20States%20land%20borders%20with,extended%20in%2030%2Dday%20increments](https://www.reuters.com/world/us/us-land-border-restrictions-extended-with-canada-mexico-2021-05-20/#:%7E:text=United%20States%20land%20borders%20with,extended%20in%2030%2Dday%20increments).

Comment: What happens at June 21 is they will almost certainly extend the restrictions for another month.  They've been doing it month by month since March 2020 and there's no indication that there will be any change this month.

Comment: The US land border is open for spouses and children of US citizens so it won’t be a problem, unless the rules become more strict in the future.

Comment: @JonathanReez *shouldn't be a problem, but probably will be

Comment: “ but I know people who have had a very stressful time crossing” - were they denied after all or were they allowed to enter? I’m sure it won’t be a 1 minute border crossing but the border guards don’t really have a reason to reject you.

Comment: @JonathanReez I don't have the time nor the space in comments, to describe all the difficulties I have heard of, but "won't be a problem" is very unlikely.  I know of people who have been questioned for hours before being allowed in, I know of people (but don't know them) who have said their family members were denied entry despite being spouse and/or children of US citizens (but traveling without US passport or other US issued ID).  I know US citizens (traveling with US passport etc.) who have had problems, been overly questioned (and more), regarding crossing for non-essential reasons...

Comment: Thank you all again for the help on this one. I don’t doubt that the border crossing would not be without difficulty. The US border agents can be tough at the best of times and always seem suspicious of me as a non-US citizen when I enter with my US citizen family. Add covid and a travel ban to the mix and a US citizen child travelling on a UK passport and I would expect a difficult time.

Comment: Your comments about the ESTA makes me wonder whether we may even be denied boarding by the airline in the U.K. as they usually ask to see US passports for US citizens as part of the check in process.

Comment: @Needtotravel I have indeed heard of airlines denying boarding to US citizens who lack US passports, but I believe all of these cases involved people born in the US.  In your child's case, the airline is less likely to suspect that your child is a US citizen.  There is still a chance that she would be denied boarding, so in the end, if you cannot get a better solution from a consular officer such as an emergency passport, you'll just have to decide whether you can accept the risk of trying with ESTA: at least she was born abroad and she's never yet applied for a CRBA nor a US passport.

Comment: This is unfortunately wrong and bad advice. US citizens may not apply for ESTA (it might technically work, but it is still invalid). Contact your local embassy for help or delay your travel. And consider for the next child to get a passport while you have time.

Comment: Thank you @Aganju. It was not lack of planning that leaves her without a US passport. We have been trying since she was born last year to get an appointment at the embassy in London to register the birth and apply for a passport. Due to covid the embassy has not been providing these services until recently. Even now there are only a handful of appointments per week and a large backlog of people in our position. We will continue to try with the embassy, I had just hoped there may be another solution!

Comment: @Hilmar I am in basically the same situation as the original author (child hasn't been naturalized but has claims to citizenship - has a German passport but no US passport).  I applied for an ESTA for my child and it was approved.  Based on what you know now, will I run into difficulties?  Thanks.